# How to have multiple git branches that are based on one main branch?

Tags: git

I'm still relatively new to git / Github and struggling with the following:

I have a repo with the branch **main**. I've created a couple of new branches that are based on **main**. I want to be working on these new branches individually, but sometimes I would like to change some 'core features' and change the **main** branch, and eventually also see these changes on the other branches.

I'm not sure how to do this. I've already created the repo and branches (also remote), but if I change the **main** branch then I don't know how to reflect those changes on the other branches.

Comment: From the other branches you can `git rebase main` to update them to include the latest changes from the `main` branch.

Comment: If you are new to Git/GitHub and want to stay within tools you are familiar with (such as pull requests) you can also, after updating `main` create a new branch from main and create a pull request from the feature branch into that new branch. The result of that PR will generate the same outcome as `rebase` but within the GUI tools of GitHub. Keep working in the new branch and delete the old feature branch.